# error: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [food_app] lib\auth\sign_in.dart:36)

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I add user data to provider, here my code but get error

```
  final User? user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  userProvider.addUserData(
    currentUser: user,
    userEmail: user?.email,
    userImage: user?.photoURL,
    userName: user?.displayName,
     );
```

Comment: there are some good answers here to help you. How about accepting one of them as an answer or give some feedback?

Answer (score 2):

just replace `currentUser: user,` with `currentUser: user!,`

Answer (score 2):

Your User is nullable. This means that `User?` and `User` are two different types. Try using a null check `(!)` as `user!`.
Or you could manually check if the user is null and act differently based on the response.

```
final User? user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
if (user!=null) {
  newUser = user as User;
 userProvider.addUserData(
    currentUser: newUser,
    userEmail: newUser.email,
    userImage: newUser.photoURL,
    userName: newUser.displayName,
     );
} else {
  //Other stuff
}
```

or

```
 final User? user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
if (user!=null) {
  User newUser = (email: user.email, photoURL: user.photoURL, displayName: user.displayName)
 userProvider.addUserData(
    currentUser: newUser,
    userEmail: newUser.email,
    userImage: newUser.photoURL,
    userName: newUser.displayName,
     );
} else {
  //Other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**just use this "toString" and solve the problem, like this**

```
final User? user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
 
  userProvider.addUserData(
     currentUser: user!,
     userName: user.displayName.toString(),
     userEmail: user.email.toString(),
     userImage: user.photoURL.toString(),
 );
```